# AWS Lambda POST is not executing

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm trying to setup a lambda that does an http post after a file is uploaded to my s3 bucket. I've looked at a bunch of examples and this is what I've come up with but for some reason when I test the function it is not executing the post.

I'm running the lambda in a nodejs environment. I've verified I can read the s3 bucket and get the file and its contents.

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');

const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
    };
    const file = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    let statusCode;
    await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('postFile');
        var options = {
            'method': 'POST',
            'hostname': 'hostname',
            'path': '/path/to/endpoint',
            'headers': {
                'auth': 'authToken'
            },
            'maxRedirects': 20
        };

        console.log("Creating request");
        var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
            statusCode = res.statusCode;
            resolve(statusCode);
            var chunks = [];

            res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                console.log('on Data')
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });

            res.on("end", function (chunk) {
                console.log('on end');
                var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                console.log(body.toString());
            });

            res.on("error", function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
        });

        console.log("Creating postData");
        var postData = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\n" +
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upfile\"\r\n" +
            "Content-Type: \"{Insert_File_Content_Type}\"\r\n\r\n" +
            file.Body.toString() +
            "\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--";

        console.log("postData", postData);

        req.setHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW');

        console.log("Writing postData");
        req.write(postData);
        console.log("Ending Request");
        req.end();
    });
    console.log(statusCode);
    return statusCode;
};
```

When the lambda executes it just times out. I can see the log statements that it got to `req.end()` but that seems to be the end of the logs.

I've set a timeout of 3, 15, and 60 seconds and all with the same result on it timing out.

Currently this is a manual process of when I get an file I have to make a REST call to post the file using POSTMAN and I did copy its code help for the call.

Comment: Are you sure that the endpoint you're hitting allows connections from AWS?

Comment: I just added made sure the lamba and the application ec2 instance were on the VPC but I'm still not seeing traffic.

Comment: If your Lambda is connected to a VPC you need either a NAT GW or a VPC Endpoint in order the Lambda can access S3.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're closing your request early by resolving the promise with the status code prior to completing the post request. AWS Lambda will exit once all promises have been resolved which is terminating your POST request. Put the resolve in the res.on("end", ...) block. See below.

```js
    var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
            statusCode = res.statusCode;
            var chunks = [];

            res.on("data", function (chunk) {
                console.log('on Data')
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });

            res.on("end", function (chunk) {
                console.log('on end');
                var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                console.log(body.toString());
                resolve(statusCode);
            });

            res.on("error", function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
        });
```

Comment: That does not seem to be resolving the issue. When I execute the lamba it just times out, I have it set to 15 seconds. Looking at the logs I am not seeing any of the logs in the call backs on 'data', 'end', or 'error'
I checked my application logs and I'm not seeing anything indicating it hit the endpoints. It is giving all the appearance of not sending the POST request.